# Sending char to linked list in C

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, char

Thanks very much now program works fine.
Still i want to understand something, i get 2 warnings with this:

|36|warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'strcspn' [enabled by default]|

|55|warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'strcpy' [enabled by default]|

```
typedef struct a nodo;
struct a
{
    int cant;
    char cad[30];
    nodo * sig;
};


void insertar (nodo**,nodo *);
void mostrarlista (nodo *);
void borrarlista(nodo**);
nodo * nuevonodo(void);


int main (void)
{
nodo *pi=NULL,*q,datos;
q=NULL;
char cad[30];
int cod,N=4,digito,j;

    printf("Ingrese Codigo Postal, 0 para finalizar:");
    gets(cad);
    fflush(stdin);

        while ((cad!=NULL))
        {
            cad[strcspn(cad,"\n")] = '\0';
            if (strcmp(cad, "0") == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
            digito=1;
            j=0;
            for (j = 0; j<N; j++)
            {
                if (!isdigit((unsigned char) cad[j]))
                {
                    digito = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (digito && cad[N] == '\0')
            {
                //cod=atoi(cad);//Esto me come los 0?
                q=nuevonodo();
                strcpy(q->cad, cad);
                q->cant=1;
                insertar(&pi,q);
                printf("Ingrese Siguiente Codigo Postal, 0 para finalizar:");
                gets(cad);
                fflush(stdin);
            }
                else
                {
                    printf("Codigo Postal Incorrecto\n");
                    printf("Ingrese Codigo Postal, 0 para finalizar:");
                    gets(cad);
                    fflush(stdin);
                }
        }
        system("cls");
        mostrarlista(pi);
        borrarlista(&pi);

        getch();
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char cad` is just 1 character, not a string.

Comment: change **gets(cad);** to **fgets(cad,30,stdin);**

Comment: It should be `char cad[30]`, and then you assign it with `strcpy(q->cad, cad);`

Comment: Hint: '5' - '0' == 5, '8' - '0' == 8.

Comment: q->cad=cad;, like above said, fix it. should be **char cad[size]** and not **char cad**

Comment: When it says implicit definition that means you haven't included the header file.

Comment: Add _#include <string.h>_ to the top of the file

Comment: the posted code does not show any #include statements.  It this is the actual code, then there should be lots more warnings as the code needs `#include <stdio.h>` `#include <string.h>`  `#include <ctype.h>` and perhaps a few others.  However, `gets()` is no longer part of the language, use `fgets()` with the appropriate parameters.  the C standard specifically states that `fflush(stdin)` is not defined.  Therefore, suggest: `while( getchar() != EOF );`

Comment: For readability by us humans, Please consistently indent the code.  Do not use tabs for indenting.  suggest 4 spaces after EVERY opening brace '{' and un-indent before every closing brace '}'.  It is also a good practice to separate code blocks (if, else, while, do, for, etc) with a blank line.

Comment: try reading the man page for `strcpy()`, etc as each man page includes the info on what header files needs to be included.

Comment: The question and posted code is a prime example of why the posted code must include the #include statements

Comment: Please, for readability and for ease of documentation, only one variable declaration per line of code and only one variable declaration per statement

Comment: the function: `getch()` available in certain instruction headers is not generally available, so not portable.  Suggest using `getchar()` instead

Comment: the local variable `N` is initialized to 4 and never changed.  It would be much better to remove that local variable and place this statement near the top of the code: `#define N (4)`

Comment: regarding this line: `while ((cad!=NULL))`   cad will never be equal to NULL as `cad[]` is an array on the stack and in C, the name of an array degrades to the address of the array and since the array is on the stack, it will ALWAYS have an address that is not NULL

Answer (score 0):

after applying the comments, cleaning up the code, removing duplicate code, this is the result.

It cleanly compiles, but has not been tested.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define N (4)

typedef struct a nodo;
struct a
{
    int cant;
    char cad[30];
    nodo * sig;
};


void insertar (nodo**,nodo *);
void mostrarlista (nodo *);
void borrarlista(nodo**);
nodo * nuevonodo(void);


int main (void)
{
    nodo *pi = NULL;
    nodo *q  = NULL;
    //nodo datos;

    char cad[30];
    //int  cod;
    int  digito;
    int  j;

    printf("Ingrese Codigo Postal, 0 para finalizar:");



    while ( fgets(cad, sizeof(cad), stdin) )
    {
        // eliminate trailing newline
        cad[strcspn(cad,"\n")] = '\0';

        // if '0' is first digit entered, exit while loop
        if ( '0' ==  cad[0] )
        { // then user wants to quit entering data
            break;
        }


        // verify contents of cad[] as 4 digits
        digito=1;

        for (j = 0; j<N; j++)
        {
            if (!isdigit((unsigned char) cad[j]))
            {
                digito = 0;
                //break; a user input error is not a reason to quit program
            }
        }

        if (digito && (cad[N] == '\0') )
        { // then valid 4 digit input
            //cod=atoi(cad);//Esto me come los 0?
            // allocate struct
            q=nuevonodo();
            // fill in fields in struct
            strcpy(q->cad, cad);
            q->cant=1;
            // insert struct into linked list
            insertar(&pi,q);

            printf("Ingrese Siguiente Codigo Postal, 0 para finalizar:");
        }

        else
        { // else invalid input, report problem to user
            printf("Codigo Postal Incorrecto\n");
            printf("Ingrese Codigo Postal, 0 para finalizar:");
        } // end if
    } // end while

    system("cls");
    mostrarlista(pi);
    borrarlista(&pi);

    // wait for user to enter any char before exiting program
    while( EOF != getchar());
    getchar();
    return 0;
} // end function: main
```